# How to display nested array object in angular api call

Tags: json, angular6, arrayobject

```
<div *ngFor="let item of category">
    {{item.categories.categories.id}}
</div>
```

That's the data fetched from api. By nested array I can't display this data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of category">
   <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.categories">
       {{subItem.categories.id}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

As there are nested array, you have to loop over again for inner array

Comment: core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '{"categories":[{"categories":{"id":1,"name":"Delivery"}},{"categories":{"id":2,"name":"Dine-out"}}]

Comment: Can you add proper response you are getting? and output you want